# Recorrer array php en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, ajax

Buen día

Amigos necesito enviar por ajax un array que esta en una variable de session en laravel, trato de recorrer el array pero no puedo pasarle la llave que identifica cada posicion del array, el objetivo de recorrer el array es para enviar un nuevo array en un orden especifico

Este es codigo que tengo.

```
 <script>
    var factura = new Array();
    var count = <?php echo count(session('carrito')); ?>;
    var posicion;
    for (var i=1; i<= count; i++)
    {

        posicion ="<?php echo session('carrito.1.nombre') ?>";
        factura.push([posicion]);

    }
 </script>
```

No he podido concatenar la variable i del for en la llave de la session para poder leer este array.

Les agradezo su colaboración.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres hacer es recorrer un array que tienes en una sesión de PHP a través de JavaScript? ¿No sería mejor obtener primero ese array por Ajax, hacer el procesamiento que requieres y luego la otra petición para enviar el resultado de la misma?

Comment: Ya lo logre hacer, lo que hice fue recorrer en php el array y pasar el valor a un array js. Fue la opcion mas rapida. Muchas gracias.